# ListView swipe animation

Tags: android, listview, animation

My ListView changes its content when swiping left or right. I would like to have an animation. The old content should leave on one side and the new content should enter on the other but I have no idea how to do it.

Maybe you have some ideas. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of ListView do you have? What GUI framework are you using? There are bunches of 'em.

Comment: I'm new in android programming so I don't know if I answer correctly. My ListView includes TextViews with Strings. Where do I find my GUI framework?

Comment: Post your layout file

Comment: I've edited my question. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem. Now, I use a ViewFlipper.

Layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/viewflipper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/listView" />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/listView2" />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/listView3" />

        </ViewFlipper>
    </LinearLayout>
```

In MainActivity:

```
mListView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MainActivity.this) {
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.in_from_left);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.out_to_right);
                viewFlipper.showNext();
            }

            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.in_from_right);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.out_to_left);
                viewFlipper.showPrevious();
            }
        });
```